# Separating Knowledge Base from Predicates, get "undefined procedure"

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Why isn't `father/2` recognized and why can't I load a file that calls `father/2`?

**theogony.pl**

```
father(kronos, zeus).
father(zeus, ares).
```

**mythos.pl**

```
consult('theogony.pl').

%% --
%% X is an ancestor of Y
%% --

ancestor(X,Y) :-
    father(X,Y).

ancestor(X,Y) :-
    ancestor(X,Z),
    ancestor(Z,Y).
```

**swipl**

```
?- consult('mythos.pl'). 
   false.
?- consult('theogony.pl').
   true.
?- father(X,zeus).
   ERROR: Unknown procedure: father/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Comment: Most Prolog users would use this at the command line: `?- [mythos,theogony].` Also many Prolog programmers would make a module of each file and export the predicates and not have a consult in a file but use `use_module/2`.

Comment: I tried `use_module` and got the same error. I began `theogony` with :- module(theogony,[father/2]). and then called `use_module(theogony, father).` to no avail.

Comment: Hopefully helpful: see the `:- use_module('file1'...` example at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=defmodule

Comment: Easiest solution: change line `consult('theogony.pl').` to `:- consult('theogony.pl').` so it actually *runs* `consult` as an action, rather than considering it to be a rule/fact.

Comment: Given your swipl `?- consult('theogony.pl'). -> true` followed by `?- father(X, zeus). -> ERROR` I guess you have two different files both called "theogony.pl" in different folders and one is empty and Prolog sees it, and the other is open in your editor. Or you have one actually called "theogony.pl" which is empty and one you are writing "father/2" into with a typo in the filename.

Comment: Use the *directive* `:- include('thheogony.pl'),' or `ensure_loaded/1` instead. Otherwise, use the module system.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I only have one `theogony.pl` and it is not empty.

Comment: @mac389 In a SWI Prolog toplevel I query `edit(file('theogony.pl')).` then copy in the two lines from your question, save, then `consult('theogony.pl').` which is `true.` then `father(X, zeus).` which gives `X = kronos.`. If you do that, does it work? What if you query `?- absolute_file_name('theogony.pl', F).`? Since you also get a true when you consult but it doesn't load father/2, it is reading some file (no permission error) and that file does not have valid father/2 in it. There aren't many options left: path confusion with multiple files, typos or unsaved files are all I can think of.